# dictionary with dictionary for data

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
m1 = {'name':john smith,'username':js111,'password':xxxx,'date':1-1-1111,'email':js111@hotmail.com}
m2 = {'name':mike smith,'username':ms111,'password':xxxx,'date':1-1-1111,'email':ms111@hotmail.com}
```

alright so i have 2 dictionaries above. how can i list m1 and m2 etc. under one dictionary so i can access a list of all my dictionaries that i can interact with. should i just use list[m1,m2]? or would that not work and make m1,m2 as a string inside the list[]... i want to display my {m1},{m2} etc as a single list that i can interact with on a GUI. which when clicked can then open the {m1} individually showing the information in a seperate screen...

i have the GUI screens and feature setup, dont need help with that portion. just the direction of which way i can make 1 list of all my dictionaries which allows me to still interact with them. rather than just show them.

for example, i want to display all {m1},{m2}, etc in one list. then if i add a search bar, i want to be able to search through {m1},{m2}, etc... in another window of GUI i want to be able to get the 'email' from inside the {m1} singlely or 'email' from both {m1},{m2} for a mass email feature. so i have to be able to interact with them as a dictionary.

if you have tkinter and would like to see my app it may clearify what i am attempting.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/home/lubuntu/subscription_app

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
#from subscription_app.enter import *
import tkFileDialog


class admin_main(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # add all "def xx()" to show on Frame
        self.initUI()
        self.menubar()
        self.onExit()
        self.statusbar()
        self.bottom_button()
        self.listbox_members()
        self.labels()
        self.listbox_info()

    def initUI(self):
        # parent border of Frame
        self.parent.title("cxvbfdbfdbvfvfv")
        self.centerWindow()
        self.grid()

    def centerWindow(self):
        # centers main window when opened
        w = 600
        h = 500
        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def menubar(self):
        # create top menu bar
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        # create drop menu
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Create member list")#command=)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Load member list")#command=)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Email")#command=)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)

#### grid row 0 ####

    def labels(self):
        # create frames for labels
        lb1 = Frame(self)
        lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
        lb2 = Frame(self)
        lb2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
        # create labels
        lbl1 = Label(lb1, text="Members List:")
        lbl2 = Label(lb2, text="Member Information:")
        # grid the labels in frame
        lbl1.pack(side=TOP)
        lbl2.pack(side=TOP)

#### grid row 1 ####           

    def listbox_members(self):
        # create the frame
        lbframe = Frame(self)
        lbframe.grid(row=1, column=0,  sticky=S+W)
        # create a listbox and scrollbar as children of the frame
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(lbframe, orient="vertical")
        lb = Listbox(lbframe, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, selectmode=SINGLE)
        scrollbar.config(command=lb.yview)
        # pack the listbox and scrollbar in the frame
        lb.grid()
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
        # text items inside box
        for line in range(100):
            lb.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

    def listbox_info(self):
        # create the frame
        lbmframe = Frame(self)
        lbmframe.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        # create the listbox for member info
        listSelection = Listbox(lbmframe, height=4, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        # grid the listbox into frame
        listSelection.pack(fill=Y, expand=True)
        # information inside listbox
        for x in "ABCD":
            listSelection.insert(END, x + ": ?")

#### grid row 2 ####            

    def bottom_button(self):
        # create the Frames
        save_edit = Frame(self)
        save_edit.grid(row=2, column=1)
        add_delete = Frame(self)
        add_delete.grid(row=2, column=0)
        # create the buttons
        editbutton = Button(save_edit, text="Edit member details")
        saveButton = Button(save_edit, text="Save member details") ##, command=)
        addButton = Button(add_delete, text="Add member")
        deletebutton = Button(add_delete, text="Delete member")
        # grid the button into Frame
        editbutton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)
        saveButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=10)
        addButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)
        deletebutton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=10)

#### grid row 3 ####

    def statusbar(self):
        # create the Frame 
        sb = Frame(self)
        sb.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        # create the details of the status bar
        status = Label(sb, text="preparing to do nothing", relief=SUNKEN, anchor=S)
        # grid the status bar into Frame
        status.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)

#### definitions for buttons/labels/menu ####

    def onExit(self):
        # Used for "exit" in menubar
        self.quit()

#### start loop/app ####    

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = admin_main(root)
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure want you intend to do. Please be more specific and elaborate like want exact Output you intend. you have mentioned the input but output that you intend is not clear.
Anyways here is my assumptions for your output:

```
# input
m1 = {'name':'john smith','username':'js111','password':'xxxx','date':'1-1-1111','email':'js111@hotmail.com'}
m2 = {'name':'mike smith','username':'ms111','password':'xxxx','date':'1-1-1111','email':'ms111@hotmail'}

# output 1 as list
>>> list((m1,m2))
[{'username': 'js111', 'date': '1-1-1111', 'password': 'xxxx', 'name': 'john smith', 'email': 'js111@hotmail.com'},
{'username': 'ms111', 'date': '1-1-1111', 'password': 'xxxx', 'name': 'mike smith', 'email': 'ms111@hotmail'}]

>>> wrap = {}
>>> wrap['m1']= m1
>>> wrap['m2'] = m2
# output 2 as dict of dict
>>> wrap
{'m1': {'username': 'js111', 'date': '1-1-1111', 'password': 'xxxx', 'name': 'john smith', 'email': 'js111@hotmail.com'},
'm2': {'username': 'ms111', 'date': '1-1-1111', 'password': 'xxxx', 'name': 'mike smith', 'email': 'ms111@hotmail'}}
```

Comment: hey , thanks for reply... i need output 2 im pretty sure. that should allow me to call variable "wrap" in your example, in a listbox. in the listbox i should be able to have it show 'm1','m2' etc (just the key inside wrap variable)... then when i click on the m1 or m2 , it will open up the dictionary  of m1,m2 (value of wrap variable)... please correct me if im wrong!

Comment: ill try to rephrase alittle , maybe more understanding... i will be intending to display dictionaries({m1},{m2} on a screen (not there information inside, just their title) . when i click on whatever specific dictionary {m1} or {m2}, it will then show me all the value information pertaining to that specific dictionary in another display... using your second output i can use wrap for variable and turn the "m1" name in my case into something searchable for the user to see.

Comment: as per your comments output 2 will be the one you require.